# How can we find out if a username and email address already exists in mongodb..?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, rest

my code is

```
User.find({$or:[{'email':req.body.email},{'username':req.body.username}]})
    .exec()
    .then(user=>{
        if(user.length >=1){
            
                return res.status(409).json({
                    message: 'Email and Username exixts'
                }) 
            
        }
    else{

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,(err,hash)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error:err
                })
            } else{
                
                const user = new User({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    email: req.body.email,
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: hash
                })
                user
                .save()
                .then(result=>{
                    console.log(result)
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: 'User created'
                    })
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error:err
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

here my code works but its not send a valid error message if email and username doesn't exit. Here I can send only email doesn't exit message how can i send username doesn't exist message here. I am stuck here somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.. I changed the code as below , now its work

```
User.find({$or:[{'email':req.body.email},{'username':req.body.username}]})
.exec()
.then(user=>{
    if(user.length >=1){
            let errors ={}
            if (user[0].email === req.body.email){
                errors.email = "Email already exists"
            } else if(user[0].username === req.body.username) {
                errors.username = "User Name already exists"
            }
            return res.status(409).json(errors)
        
    }
    else{

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,(err,hash)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error:err
                })
            } else{
                
                const user = new User({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    email: req.body.email,
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: hash
                })
                user
                .save()
                .then(result=>{
                    console.log(result)
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: 'User created'
                    })
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error:err
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```